# Defining a method via constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

I have defined a JS class:

```
class Animation{

    constructor(name, el, func){
        this.name = name;
        this.target = el;
        this.animate = func.bind(this, this.target);
        this.running = true;

    }
// more methods here controlling animations 
}
```

When creating an Animation object, I would like to have this behaviour:

```
... new Animation("animation", objToOperateOn, (target) => {
   doStuff();
   this.anAnimationMethod() // causes error because this is undefined
});
```

How can i get the anonymous function given as an argument to the constructor to have a refrence to the Animation object in the **this** keyword? The **bind** method that I'm using in the constructor doesn't seem to work, as logging **this** on the arrow function returns undefined.

PS. The *target* argument would be useless given we have a refrence to **this**, i just got it there for testing purposes.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: First step is to use a plain function and not an `=>` function; the latter don't work with `.bind`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seemed to have fixed my problem. I'm pretty new with JS so I'm missing a lot of those JS specific stuff. Guess this is a closed topic?